# How to access property cross class and cross file in Python?

Tags: python, tornado

Now I need a property which in another class to do something in one class.

just like:

```
a.py

class A:
    def __init__(self, io_loop):         # the same io_loop instance 
        self.access = None
        self.w_id = None
        self.io_loop = io_loop

    @gen.coroutine
    def setup(self):
        # `async_client` has the `get`, 'post', 'put', 'delete' methods 
        self.access = yield async_client()

    @gen.coroutine
    def do_something(self):
        self.w_id = self.access.get('w_id')
        ...

    def run(self):
        self.io_loop.run_sync(self.setup)
        self.io_loop.spawn_callback(self.do_something)
        self.io_loop.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    a.run()
```

-

```
b.py

class B:
    def __init__(self, io_loop):
        self.w_id = None
        self.io_loop = io_loop           # the same io_loop instance    

    # How can i get the w_id from `class A`     

    def run(self):
        ... 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    b.run()
```

**Notice**:

when zone_id of `class B` is not None, `class B` can do next. that's means, if `class A` zone_id is None, `class B` will waiting for it.

And the `class A` and `class B` only could initialize one instance.

**the `class A` and `class B` in differents files.**

Comment: Can class `B` hold a reference to class `A`?

Comment: This is code smell, but you could simply make and treat `w_id` as a class variabe, so `A.w_id` everywhere.

Comment: @shuttle87 but `class A` itself need init. and only has one instance

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the `w_id` isn't class variable...

Comment: @agnewee Right, I'm saying make it a class variable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorrt, i forget explaining that the `class A` and `class B` in different py files.

Comment: You need to add `import a` also.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are in different files in order to use class variables.

Comment: I means, only can init one instance `A` and `B`, now there is a instance `a` in `a.py` and `b` in `b.py`, so i can't declare `A` instance in `B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access that variable until you create an instance that initializes. Otherwise, `w_id` doesn't exist in `A`.

If you want to give `w_id` an arbitrary value for access from other classes, put it as a class variable, means you write directly `w_id = 'some value'` inside class `A` with the same indentation as the `def`s:

```
class A:
    w_id = something
    def __init__(self):
        ...
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.w_id = A.w_id
```

Otherwise, you need an instance of `A`, like that:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        a = A()
        a.do_something()
        self.w_id = a.w_id
```

The only other option is to create the same functions inside `B`:

```
class B:
    ...
    @gen.coroutine 
    def setup(self): 
        # `async_client` has the `get`, 'post', 'put', 'delete' methods
        self.access = yield async_client()   
    @gen.coroutine 
    def do_something(self): 
        self.w_id = self.access.get('w_id') 
        ...
```

As you mentioned that io_loop is the same instance in all of the classes, it might occur that you need to create a copy of it if your functions uses it. You can't change a variable and expect it to stay unchanged.

Comment: @agnewee If you launch b.py, and imports a.py then no instance of A will be created before, because `__name__='__main__'` will be triggered **only** in b.py. a.py is only imported as a library.

Comment: In fact, the `A` and `B` use the same `ioloop` instance, so in the context, they already exists instance...

Comment: So add a class variable. As I mentioned, the w_id in A will not exist until the initialization will happen, and you don't allow that. However, there is a thirds method. I add it now.

Comment: I try it, but no effect. In `a.py` i declare a class variable `W_ID=None`, then `from a import A` at `b.py`. in `b.py` the A.W_ID always is `None`.

Comment: Just updated it. And sure, you need to hold an instance so you can change the variable. You can't change the values inside a generic class on the run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123624/discussion-between-agnewee-and-uriel-eli).